# C#,what is the simplest way to add a class in List of class

Tags: c#, list, class

I have record of a class multiple time.I make List and create object of Statsand then add to my List but the most recent record is copied by all. here is my code

```
List<Account> account = accountDao.All().Where(a => a.Role ==
Role.Distributor && a.ParentAccount.Id==1&&a.Active).ToList();
ViewBag.Accounts = account;
List<Stats> statsforRegions = new List<Stats>();
foreach (Account dist in account)
{
    List<int> userIdss = new List<int>();
    List<int> accountIdss = new List<int>();
    Stats stt = new Stats();
    stt=stats;
    getUserIdsRecursive(dist, userIdss, accountIdss);
    stt = calculate(stt, userIdss, accountIdss);
    statsforRegions.Add(stt);

}
ViewBag.StatsForRegions = statsforRegions;
```

Comment: Please edit your tags, as this is C#, not C.

Comment: I don't understand your question and problem ?  Like 'but the most recent record is copied by all.'

Comment: What does `calculate` look like?

Comment: @Tommo1977 for exaple i have record like name=Nafees and other properties when add this class in List already records in the list get same record like name=Nafees

Comment: He's saying that the last created item fills the entire list (because a new item is not created .-see answer by GazTheDestoyer

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen calculate is a method that returns a Stats.

Comment: and why you declare a new variable "stt", assign it to "stats" without using it and then assign "stt" to the result of your calculate Method? - also look answer below.. refers to the same

Comment: stats have some general record i assign it to my new object and then replace some of its values by calculate method.

Comment: @MuhammadNafees I wrote a short example for you to try.  Check my answer below.

Comment: @Tommo1977 I have the idea how to add but here i failed.i want to know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of adding objects to a List

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<MyObject> MyList = new List<MyObject>();

        for (int x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
        {
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            obj.Id = x;

            MyList.Add(obj);                       
        }

        //now show the list

        foreach(MyObject obj in MyList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Id.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}    
}
```

I wrote a fiddle for you too https://dotnetfiddle.net/cnNiI5

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Stats` object and assigning it to `stt`.

```
Stats stt = new Stats();
```

You then assign another object (`stats`) to `stt`, meaning the original object is thrown away.

```
stt = stats.
```

Your code does not show what `stats` is, but I assume it is the "recent record" your refer to.

Comment: After assigning stt=stats stt record is different but when i add this object in statsforRegions.Add(stt); it replace all other record in the list

Comment: then I can only assume that you are returning the same object from calculate() every time.

Comment: No no after calculate method i have the record that i need.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `calculate` function is returning same value and

```
stats
```

is unchanged.

```
    stt=stats;
    getUserIdsRecursive(dist, userIdss, accountIdss);
    stt = calculate(stt, userIdss, accountIdss);
```

Comment: yes after calculate stt has record that i need.But when i add this object to list its record is copied by all other records in list